MakeFile Tools running -f even with MakeArgs set to -C
I am currently trying to run a MakeFile from MakeFile tools, Ive been googling for hours why it wasn't working from the default. until I found people telling me to use -C instead.
I tried to run the makefile having my current config set to have the MakeArgs of ["-C (directory folder)"].
however when I run build, makefile tools decides to do "mingw32-make -f (directory of makefile) -C (directory folder)"
this is my current config:
"makefile.configurations": [
        {
            "name": "config",
            "makeArgs": ["-C ${workspaceRoot}"],
            "makefilePath": "src/MakeFile"
        }
    ]

for clarity sake yes the Configuration is set to "config"

Not quite sure what desired behavior is from your post. -C means to run make in a different folder. In your sample the workspace root folder. -f to use one or many files when running make. The path to -f is relative the make invocation, not the -C directory. If the current makefilePath is meant to be relative the workspace root you should have that too in the path, like "${workspaceRoot}/src/Makefile. If you could clarify with an error message or otherwise the expected behavior it would help me understanding. Passing -f and -C together is nothing wrong in itself.

the problem is no matter how i change the config makefile tools always passes -f. which is the error. it should be only passing -C with my current config. however it is not. read my config I posted and you'll very clearly see I'm not passing both

or to clarify, its passing it in the wrong order. from what i've read the current config should run "mingw32-make -C(Directory folder) -f src/makefile" however it instead runs the the way posted above, where it first runs -f, and than the -C which is where I'm running into issues

Fixed the issue, it was because i was using makefilePath and not makeDirectory

OP says using makeDirectory rather than makefilePath fixed the issue:
"makefile.configurations": [
        {
            "name": "config",
            "makeDirectory": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
        }
    ]


this is indeed correct
